# Bootstrap : navbar doesn't close when we click, responsive issue

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, navbar

I have some trouble to hide my navbar when it's responsive.

When we click on the button the navbar don't close everytime..

If someone can help me, i'm on an Angular 9 project.

Demo :
http://jordanbretton.fr

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jordan Bretton</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

navbar.component.html :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="home">Jordan Bretton</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Accueil</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="skills">Compétences</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="about">À propos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="projects">Projets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://linkedin.com/in/jordanbretton" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://gitlab.com/JowB" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-git-square fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I really don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: The button in the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find why your aria-expanded="false" stays at true even if you click on it. Inspecting your website, you can see that all the classes are changing but aria-expanded is changing from true to true... Then all the classes go back to true instead of false.

Anyway if I were you I'd use one of these libraries with bootstrap on Angular to avoid that kind of problem.

[Ng bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

[Ngx bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/)

Comment: I used ngx-bootstrap, delete all the scripts and links for bootstrap in the index.html and it's work ! Thank's !